# JS Contenteditable Underline not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, execcommand

I just ran into a bug in `document.execCommand` I think. Here is the problem.

```js
$("#underline-btn").click(function() {
  document.execCommand("underline");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true">This is a contenteditable div. To recreate the bug, click inside this div and press the underline button. Now type a word or a letter. Then press backspace and delete whatever you typed. Now press the underline button again. Start typing something. The word you type will still be underlined.</div>
<button id="underline-btn">Underline</button>
```

To recreate the bug:

1. Click inside the `contenteditable` `div` and press the `underline button`
2. Now type a word or a letter
3. Then press `backspace` and delete whatever you typed.
4. Now press the `underline button` again
5. Start typing something
6. The word you type is still underlined

Ideally, clicking the `underline button` again should have removed the underline formatting for the words you typed after, but for some reason it does not.

I don't understand why this is the case. It works fine with `bold` and `italics`, but with `underline`, it messes up and keeps the formatting.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide a workaround or something that would resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: if you backspace to a space before the word that you typed, the error doesn't seem to occur. that's what i did (accidentally) when following your instructions to recreate the bug, and it didn't occur. Also, if you highlight an underlined word and press the underline button, it will remove the underline (this is my understanding of how it should work)

Comment: @RachelGallen yes, thank you very much for your input. I didn't realize that. good to know. however, i'm building an editor and this seems to be really annoying. It might be annoying for the users as well so I'm trying to think ahead and try to fix this damn bug :)

Comment: maybe put this info in a help file? Just an idea..

Comment: Or a tooltip maybe?

Answer (score 1):

When you click the `underline` button, *«underline is toggle on/off for the selection or at the insertion point.»*

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Now when you backspace untile there is no more characters and `blur` the editable div, the inserted `<u>` tag is removed. Clicking again the button will then toggle it on again.

Try this in your own snippet:

1. Click inside the `contenteditable` `div` and press the `underline button`
2. Now type a word or a letter
3. Then press `backspace` and delete whatever you typed.
4. **Now just blur the editable field and focus again.**
5. Start typing something
6. The word you type is **are not** underlined

So what I suggest you is to make sure a selection is made to enable the underline button... So underlining only will be applyed on a selection made... Preventing the possibility of applying underlining *«at insertion point»*, which is not obvious for the user...

```js
$("[contenteditable]").on("mouseup",function(){
  selectionMade = (window.getSelection().type == "Range");  // True is there actually is a selection made.
  $("#underline-btn").prop("disabled",!selectionMade);
});


$("#underline-btn").click(function() {
  document.execCommand("underline");
  console.log("Toggled underline on a selection.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true">This is a contenteditable div. To recreate the bug, click inside this div and press the underline button. Now type a word or a letter. Then press backspace and delete whatever you typed. Now press the underline button again. Start typing something. The word you type will still be underlined.</div>
<button id="underline-btn" disabled>Underline</button>
```

And there is now a visual indication for the user as if he can use the underline button or not.